# Checking if two arrays are broadcastable in python

Tags: python, numpy

According to the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html), two arrays are broadcastable if one of the following conditions are true:

```
- The arrays all have exactly the same shape.
- The arrays all have the same number of dimensions and the length of each dimensions is either a common length or 1.
- Arrays that have too few dimensions can have their shapes prepended with a dimension of length 1 to satisfy property 2.
```

I tried to implement this in python, but having a trouble in understanding the 2nd and 3rd rule. Not getting the answer that I am expecting, but I want to know what error that I am making in my code and a possible solution to this error.

```
# Broadcastable if:
# The arrays all have exactly the same shape.

if a.shape == b.shape:
    result = True

# The arrays all have the same number of dimensions 

elif len(a.shape) == len(b.shape):

    # and the length of each dimensions is either a common length or 1.

    for i in len(a.shape):
        if len(a.shape[i] != 1):
            result = False
        else:
            result = True

# Arrays that have too few dimensions can have their shapes prepended with a dimension of length 1 to satisfy property 2

elif a.shape == () or b.shape == ():
    result = True


else:
    result = False

return result
```

Comment: Use `numpy.broadcast_arrays` and check if shapes are equal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a concise expression to check if two arrays are broadcastable:

```
In [101]: import numpy as np

In [102]: a = np.zeros((3, 1, 5))

In [103]: b = np.zeros((4, 5))

In [104]: all((m == n) or (m == 1) or (n == 1) for m, n in zip(a.shape[::-1], b.shape[::-1]))
Out[104]: True

In [105]: b = np.zeros((5, 3))

In [106]: all((m == n) or (m == 1) or (n == 1) for m, n in zip(a.shape[::-1], b.shape[::-1]))
Out[106]: False
```

Comment: Nice use of `zip_longest`.

Comment: Wouldn't `zip` be enough?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes, it would.  `zip_longest` is used to pad the "shorter" shape with 1s, but those 1s will never cause a `False` in the sequence of comparisons, so they are not necessary. I've updated the code to use `zip`.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: gives me a false negative with shapes (30, 1, 2) and (3,2). These arrays are broadcastable, yet this snippet returns false.

Comment: @Adrian, I just tried it with `a = np.zeros((30, 1, 2)) ` and `b = np.zeros((3, 2))`, and the snippet returned True.

Comment: Oh wait didn't see the `[:, :, - 1]` part! My bad.

Comment: Perhaps it should be added that this is available in numpy after 1.20.0, simply use `np.broadcast_shapes`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to implement this as code, but the way I reason things is:

- compare the shapes
- if one has fewer dimensions, add 1s at the start to match
- again compare; replace all 1s with a corresponding dimension from the other array

For example, if I have a (3,1) and (3,) array.  Expand the (3,) to (1,3).  Now change both to (3,3).

```
In [180]: A = np.ones((3,1),int); B = np.arange(3)
In [181]: A.shape
Out[181]: (3, 1)
In [182]: B.shape
Out[182]: (3,)
In [183]: (A+B)
Out[183]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])

In [184]: np.broadcast_arrays(A,B)
Out[184]: 
[array([[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]), 
 array([[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]])]
```

In another recent question I  use `broadcast_to`.  I start with a n-d array, reduce one dimension to 1 with `np.mean` (and keepdims), and then re-expand it with `broadcast_to`.

[Arbitrary N-dimensional repeat of N-dimensional numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231974/arbitrary-n-dimensional-repeat-of-n-dimensional-numpy-array/47232235#47232235)

In a recent answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47243071/901925

a (2,3) is broadcasted with a (4,3) with

`A[:, None]` makes the (4,3) into a (4,1,3) (there's an implied final ':').  `B` is automatically expanded from (2,3) to (1,2,3).  Now both can broadcast to (4,2,3).

So the (2,3) can't broadcast with (4,3) (same n-d but different values).  But it can broadcast with (4,1,3).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same thing using `numpy`'s own `broadcast` function:

```py
def can_be_broadcast(*args):
    try:
        numpy.broadcast(*args)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```